# Increasing and decreasing the height of a div using JS

Tags: javascript, html, height

I am trying to create some simple javascript to be executed when my button is clicked.

The div starts off at height 0, so it is 'minimized'. The function test() is then executed. It checks to see if the div is minimized or maximized, if it is minimized then it increases the div height by 5px until it reaches the height of 300. And likewise if the box is 'maximized' it decreases the value by 5 until it reaches 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
var current = "minimized";
var divH = document.getElementById('module').offsetHeight;

function test() {
    if (current = "minimized") {
        current = "maximized";

        while (divH < 300) {
            divH = divH+5;
        }
    }
    else {
        current = "minimized";

        while (divH > 0) {
            divH = divH-5;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is quite literally my first attempt at using javascript.

Comment: this is not going to do a good animation, you woul have to use  setTimeouts insted of that running while...

Comment: When you're checking for equality, use == or (preferably) ===  If you use just one = it will assign rather than check for equality which will generally always evaluate to true (unless you're assigning a "falsy" value.

Comment: You need to write a recursive function so that you can use it by setTimeout(function,miliseconds);

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) a div height easily and it works cross browser. While it's best to learn Javascript as the language first, you'll soon see why using a lib like jQuery is a good idea.

It will abstract away the browser inconsistencies, letting you focus on solving the business need.

```
$('#module').animate({ height: 300 });
```

Comment: Beware of the 'jQuery just for a simple thing' haters.

Comment: @rcdmk: I saw a quote here on SO that went somewhat: "The more you know about the javascript, the more you advocate the usage of tools like jQuery." It's just a smart choice to use something that abstracts browser inconsistencies away.

Comment: I'm not saying it's good or bad practice. I have a good undestanding of JS and jQuery and, like almost enyone this days, use jQuery in most of the projects and its just a 'reinvent the wheel' thig to program an animation function.

Answer (score 2):

you are changing onlyyour variable, not the actual height of the div

where you have

```
divH=divH+5;
```

add

```
document.getElementById('module').offsetHeight = divH;
```

oh, i haven't seen that, use == instead of = for the if comparison